# Usage and role of s_pins field in the VFS superblock

Tags: vfs

I study with details the structure of the VFS superblock and I noticed the field

```
struct hlist_head s_pins;
```

Even though I made an extensive search it was not possible to find info about this. I only found that this is defined and used in fs_pins.c and in functions as pin_insert & etc cetera, but there is no information about its usage and its role. In fact, I found a PIN control subsystem, but I don't know if this is the same since it seems to be associated to hardware pins and not to file systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These pins are used by the accounting subsystem: they ensure that [`acct_pin_kill`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.9/source/kernel/acct.c#L170) is called when file systems are unmounted or remounted, so that accounting can take appropriate action. (Accounting [writes information to a file](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/acct.2.html), so it needs to know when that file will no longer be writable.)

Pins were intended as a more general-purpose way for code to be attached to mounts, [but that ended up never quite getting there](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=efb170c22867cdc6f770de441bdefecec6712199).

Comment: I study the struct mount and i noticed the field mnt_pins. I suppose that its purpose is the same as the s_pins described above.

Comment: Yes, `mnt_pins` is the counterpart of `s_pins` in `struct mount`; you can see it set alongside `s_pins` in [`pin_insert`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.9/source/fs/fs_pin.c#L22).